# Creating an elegant solution to avoid HTTPServiceUnavailable

Tags: python-3.x, function, exception, error-handling, bitmex

I have one third-party API-kit module (bitmex). I have many calls to this module in my code. The problem is that this API-kit often gives me an error:

```
HTTPServiceUnavailable
```

I understand that this error is due to unstable BitMEX servers. 
But if it occurs during a trading session, it completely destroys my trading.

Here is an example of calling the bitmex module in my code:

```
balance = bitmex.User.User_getMargin(currency='XBt').result()
```

Of course, I tried to solve the problem. 
Here is the function I came up with:

```
def bitmex_error_protection(request):
    retries = 0
    while True:
        try:
            result = eval(request)
        except bravado.exception.HTTPServiceUnavailable:
            time.sleep(5)
            retries += 1
            if retries > 5:
                raise Exception("The servers are overloaded, the max number of attempts has been reached")
        else:
            return result
```

As you understand, the meaning of this function is that I pass it a request in a packed form (in a string object). 
After that, there will be "While True" until the request is executed without this error.

Here is an example of how I am now making these calls:

```
balance = bitmex_error_protection("bitmex.User.User_getMargin(currency='XBt').result()")
```

This solution works, but I understand that it is far from elegant and rests on crutches.

I will be glad if you suggest a couple of ideas or completely alternative methods for solving this problem, where I don't need to use a string object.

Maybe for this, I need to create a class?